# Override method in dart on fly (like JAVA)

Tags: dart

Is there way to overriding method in Dart like JAVA, for example:

```dart
public class A {
    public void handleLoad() {
    }
}
```

And when overriding:

```dart
A a = new A() {
    @Override
    public void handleLoad() {
        // do some code
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question and deleted my answer. I haven't seen anything like this in Dart but maybe I just don't know about it yet.

Comment: Dart language does not support anonymous classes. This and other class declarations as an expressions not allowed in Dart language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Dart does not have anonymous classes. You have to create a class that extends `A` and instantiate it.

Answer (score 4):

No but it much less useful in Dart because you can just reassign function:

```dart
typedef void PrintMsg(msg);

class Printer {
  PrintMsg foo = (m) => print(m);
}

main() {
  Printer p = new Printer()
  ..foo('Hello') // Hello
  ..foo = ((String msg) => print(msg.toUpperCase()))
  ..foo('Hello'); //HELLO
}
```

However you will need some extra boilerplate to access instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use type Function:

```
    class A {
        final Function h
        A(this.h);
        void handleLoad(String loadResult) { h(loadResult); }
    }
```

Or

```
    class A {
        final Function handleLoad;
        A(this.handleLoad);
    }

    A a = new A((String loadResult){
        //do smth.
    });
```